# WP - check_password_reset_key function always return expire key

Tags: wordpress

I used `check_password_reset_key()` function to implement function forget password on wordpress, but when I use `check_password_reset_key()` to check `($key, $user)` this function always return "expire key".

```
// Generate something random for a password reset key.
$key = wp_generate_password( 20, false );

// Now insert the key, hashed, into the DB.
if ( empty( $wp_hasher ) ) {
    require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-phpass.php';
    $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash( 8, true );
}
$hashed = $wp_hasher->HashPassword( $key );
$wpdb->update( $wpdb->users, array( 'user_activation_key' => $hashed ), array( 'user_login' => $user_login ) );
```

Check :

```
$user = check_password_reset_key( $rp_key, $rp_login );
```

Comment: Have you figured out why it happens?

Comment: I found the reason.

Comment: @AlmasAdilbek can you post your reason/solution? I'm having the same issue at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I resolved the issue by using WordPress's own function to create the password reset key: [get_password_reset_key](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_password_reset_key/).

It is quite similar to your way of doing it but it also adds the current time to the key. So, instead of

```
$hashed = $wp_hasher->HashPassword( $key );
```

it does:

```
$hashed = time() . ':' . $wp_hasher->HashPassword( $key );
```